# Class and object class

Tags: java

Design a class called Formula. Objects of this class are used to describe the details of a particular recipe and are responsible for the following information:
Ingredients: An Ingredients class object used to describe the ingredients required for the recipe. You may assume that the Name class is available to you and contains all of the features that have been re-enforced in the lectures and worksheet exercises.

I do not really understand this question. Could you guys please help me explain it.

I try to make a field like `private Ingredients ingredients` (it's right?). And in the default constructor, I use like `ingredients = new Ingredients()`; (It's right?).

Thanks

Comment: I think as our text said you should have two classes Formula and Ingredients  and the Formula class has instance from Ingredients class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you created  class type variable called ingredients..that 's right..then the purpose of doing new Ingredients () is to create an object..and assign that into reference  variable maked above..You can use private access  modifier for that reference  variable..similar  to adding private modifier  to attributes in a class.